# MongoDB - CPU utilisation goes beyond 70% on huge update

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection `test`. An update operation is done on this collection every 30 seconds. Sometimes the cpu utilization goes above 80% and connection times out. Also when I enabled profiling and checked `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`, the time taken for the update operation to complete is more than 40 seconds. Update query is very big and it looks like this.

**Update Query**

```
test.update({_id: xxxxxxxx},{ $set: { 
c_id: "5803a892b6646ad17b2b7a67", s_id: "58f29ee1d6ee0610543f152e", 
c_id: "58f29a38c91379637619605c", m: "78a3512ad29c", 
date: new Date(1505520000000), l.0.h.0.t: 0, l.0.m.0.0.t: 0, 
l.0.h.0.t: 0, l.0.m.0.0.t: 0, l.0.h.0.r: 0, l.0.m.0.0.r: 0, 
l.0.h.0.r: 0, l.0.m.0.0.r: 0, l.1.h.0.t: 0, l.1.m.0.0.t: 0, 
l.1.h.0.t: 0, l.1.m.0.0.t: 0, l.1.h.0.r: 0, l.1.m.0.0.r: 0, 
l.1.h.0.r: 0, l.1.m.0.0.r: 0, l.0.m.0.1.t: 0, l.0.m.0.1.t: 0,
l.0.m.0.1.rxb: 0, l.0.m.0.1.r: 0, 
l.1.m.0.1.t: 0, l.1.m.0.1.t: 0, l.1.m.0.1.r: 0, l.1.m.0.1.r: 0, 
l.0.m.0.2.t: 0, 
.....................
.....................
.....................
.....................
.....................
}})
```

The query is very large, I have only posted a part of the query and the schema is also very much involved. How can we improve the performance of this update query? Should I optimize schema to reduce the number of nested documents?

I would like to know what are steps I can take to improve this update query.

***.explain() output for Update Query***

```
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "test.stats",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "UPDATE",
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IDHACK"
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : []
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "abcxyz",
    "port" : 27017,
    "version" : "3.4.4",
    "gitVersion" : "988390515874a9debd1b6c5d36559ca86b4babj"
},
"ok" : 1.0
}
```

Comment: Did you try running explain on the query? Is it using right indices? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/

Comment: Do you really have to update all that data every 30s or can you limit the update to specific fields ? Hard to say without seeing the shema and the query.

Comment: @titogeo - Only `_id` is indexed. I will post the explain output.

Comment: @titogeo -  what are right indices? I have updated the question with explain output.

Comment: What is query used for the update?

Comment: @titogeo - update query is already mentioned in the question `{ $set: {.... }}`

Comment: How big is your collection? Enable verbose logs and check for anything suspicious.

Comment: @titogeo - You are asking about the total documents in the collection? How to enable verbose log? I have enabled profiling and viewing the logs in mongod.log file. There are around 4848 documents in the collection.